# str_replace works just for first element from foreach

Tags: php

I try to remove all `<p>` from a string, but in my case works just for first element from foreach.

```
$fullstring = '<ul>';
    foreach ($item['children'] as $key => $sub_item) {
       $nextElement = str_replace(array("<p>", "</p>"), array("", ""), $sub_item['content']['content']);
       $fullstring .= '<li>' . $nextElement . '</li>';
    }
$fullstring .= '</ul>';
```

The response that get (it's from logs) `$sub_item`

```
[2020-04-06 11:05:12] local.INFO: Receiving response:{"content":{"content":"<p><span>The [X] is paid for all of the Products and no other amounts are owed by the [Y] to the [X] in respect of other Products supplied by the [X].<\/span><\/p>","numbering":""},"children":[]}  
[2020-04-06 11:05:12] local.INFO: Receiving response:{"content":{"content":"<p><span>The [Y] sells the Products in accordance with this agreement in which case ownership of the Products will pass to the [Y] immediately before the Products are delivered to the [Y]&#039;s customer.<\/span><\/p>","numbering":""},"children":[]}  
[2020-04-06 11:05:12] local.INFO: Receiving response:{"content":{"content":"<p><span>they become the [Y]&#039;s property; or<\/span><\/p>","numbering":""},"children":[]}  
[2020-04-06 11:05:12] local.INFO: Receiving response:{"content":{"content":"<p><span>they are attached to or incorporated in other Products; or<\/span><\/p>","numbering":""},"children":[]}  
[2020-04-06 11:05:12] local.INFO: Receiving response:{"content":{"content":"<p><span>they are delivered to a purchaser from the [Y].<\/span><\/p>","numbering":""},"children":[]}  
[2020-04-06 11:05:12] local.INFO: Receiving response:{"content":{"content":"<p><span>If the [Y] sells the Products, the [Y] shall hold the proceeds of sale on trust for the [X] in a separate bank account.<\/span><\/p>","numbering":""},"children":[]}  
[2020-04-06 11:05:12] local.INFO: Receiving response:{"content":{"content":"<p><span>The [X] may trace the proceeds of sale that the [Y] receives into any bank or other account which the [Y] maintains.<\/span><\/p>","numbering":""},"children":[]}  
[2020-04-06 11:05:12] local.INFO: Receiving response:{"content":{"content":"<p><span>If the [Y] sells the Products, the [X] may, by written demand, require the [Y] to assign to the [X] the [Y]&#039;s rights to recover the price from its customer.<\/span><\/p>","numbering":""},"children":[]}  
[2020-04-06 11:05:12] local.INFO: Receiving response:{"content":{"content":"<p><span>The [Y] must not assign to any other person any rights arising from a sale of the Products without the [X]&#039;s written consent.<\/span><\/p>","numbering":""},"children":[]}
```

Comment: What's the value of `vardump($item['children'])`?

Comment: Are you sure this is a multi index? `$sub_item['content']['content']`

Comment: Show us value of `var_dump($item['children']);`

Comment: Yes, it's the response that I get (text from docx file). An array with multiple levels.

Comment: @Beusebiu  show it to us....

Comment: Don't describe it, show it. We can't be sure of anything or fix anything just based on a description. Programming is all about the specific details.

Comment: Sorry, I edit the post. The response if from laravel/logs..

Comment: No wonder it does not work, since your `$item['children']` is empty ...

Comment: It's not empty. I have the post edited, that's $sub_item, with it's content.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. The `$sub_item` log dump you've shown looks like JSON. Maybe something screws up during decoding? Have you tried directly dumping `$sub_item['content']['content']` in the loop?

Comment: Did you `json_decode` your `$sub_item` before you tried to access the data from it? If those logs are the result of directly logging `$sub_item` without any changes, then I'd guess you didn't. You need to decode the JSON into an array before you can get data from it.